# HtmlUnit HtmlInput sometimes does and sometimes doesn't work, without changing code?

Tags: html, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit as a Web Scraper for a website. Essentially I'm writing code to prove to learn it (and prove to myself that I can do it), but some of the code I will use in my actual project. I've run into a problem that will be very important in the upcoming project. What's happening is I'm navigating a website to get to the search feature on the website. This requires a login. I've created a dummy gmail account to login to the website. Only problem is, clicking the login button sometimes works perfectly and sometimes throws an error message. Using print statements, I can see that the button is the same whether or not the code throws the error message. Here's my code:

```
public static void main (String args[] ) throws Exception {

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    String url = "http://tappedout.net/";

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    HtmlAnchor deckBuilderLink = (HtmlAnchor) page.getByXPath("//a").get(3);
    HtmlPage deckBuilderPage = deckBuilderLink.click();


    url = deckBuilderPage.toString().substring(9).substring(0, 38);


    HtmlAnchor advancedSearchLink = (HtmlAnchor) deckBuilderPage.getByXPath("//a[@class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block active\"]").get(0);

    HtmlPage advancedSearchPage = advancedSearchLink.click();

    HtmlInput usernameInput = (HtmlInput) advancedSearchPage.getByXPath("//input[@name=\"username\"]").get(0);

    usernameInput.setValueAttribute("tappedoutScraper");

    HtmlInput passwordInput = (HtmlInput) advancedSearchPage.getByXPath("//input[@name=\"password\"]").get(0);

    passwordInput.setValueAttribute("&tappedoutScraper3");

    System.out.println(advancedSearchPage);

    HtmlInput button = (HtmlInput) advancedSearchPage.getByXPath("//input[@value=\"Log in\"]").get(0);

    System.out.println(button);

    advancedSearchPage = button.click();

    System.out.println(advancedSearchPage);

}
```

So, why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance and sorry for any poorly formatted code, this is how I learned to format it.

EDIT:
Here's the error message:

Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable for https://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/search/
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:590)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2255)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:945)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.processPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:1035)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1032)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:973)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:903)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:884)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:865)
    at Test.main(Test.java:43)

Comment: Please add the Error message and the stack trace if any.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an 503 response code is something done at the server side. Looks a bit like the server does some kind of scrapping or denial of service detection and declares the url content as temporary unavailable if he thinks the request is an attack. Have seen someone that does some random length pauses between doing the next request for the same url.